# some ffmpeg images are green, what causes this?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to stream files from an android screen to a computer. I use ffmpeg from the android to convert the raw image file to a jpg, and then I pull it to the computer. the images appear green pretty frequently (every few frames) and I'm wondering what is causing this, perhaps the rbg0 parameter?

> shell screencap | /data/local/tmp/ffmpeg/./ffmpeg.armv7 -f rawvideo
>   -s" + dimension[1].Split('\n')[0] +" -pix_fmt rgb0  -nostats -r 4  -i - -vf scale=540:960 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg -update 1 -q:v 1  - > /data/local/tmp/ffmpeg/new.jpg;

Comment: It's a bug in the capture or conversion software. Unless someone knows the bug and posts details, your best bet is to change settings and try to work around the issue.

Comment: @Sophit are you sure it's a bug rather than me passing incorrect parameters? thanks

Comment: It's possible you have a bad parameter, but ffmpeg isn't the best written software. I've often seen similar behavior from it in the past. Either way, I do suggest tweaking parameters to see if you can work around the issue.

Comment: I am only posting this as an added information, and also the use case is a bit different from the question, but IF you are assembling frames to make a movie, similar green images happen from JPEG sources if you did not include `-pix_fmt yuv420p` in your command.